# Heatmap not supporting Arabic alphabet

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn, heatmap

i can not display Arabic alphabet in y axis in heat map 
this is my code

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
heat = Heating_map.pivot("ISIC4_ARABIC", "BUSINESS_CATEGORY", "Yes")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize = (25,15))

ax = sns.heatmap(heat, cmap='coolwarm', linewidths=1, annot=True, vmax=5, fmt='.1f', square=True, cbar=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you guide people into what exactly is wrong with the output? Are the y axis tick labels not the ones you have in your dataframe?

Comment: Y axis is the one the i have problem. the alphabet is encrypted not the same language.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to write in Arabic from inside seaborn however, you may use arabic_reshaper and algorithm libraries to re-shape and reverse the text in the data frame. example:

```
!pip install arabic_reshaper
!pip install python-bidi
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi import algorithm 

# when you use pandas reshape the column you want

df['column'] = lgorithm.get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(df['column']))
```

now your column has a reshaped text. Go ahead and use seaborn heatmap

Hope this may solve your issue

Comment: if you use arabic_reshaper you also need to use python bidi module. They are old hacks. Much better to use the mplcairo backend for matplotlib which seaborn would use.